# How to get the height and width of my layout

Tags: android-layout, android-studio

Im new in programming. the codes below is getting the screen size of the device .Here is my question. how can i replace this codes to get the width and height of my relativelayout?

```
    windowwidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    windowheight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
```

Comment: you want screen size relative layou'S  size ??

Answer (score 0):

This should get you going

```
RelativeLayout relLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_file);
int width = relLayout.getWidth();
int height = relLayout.getHeight();
```

Disclaimer: I did not get a chance to test this code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It works for me.

```
RelativeLayout = relativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.id_of_relativeLayout);

relativeLayout.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int width = relativeLayout.getWidth();
        int height = relativeLayout.getHeight();
    }
}
```